# How to Fix "The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Model` instance in DRF

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and I have attempted to add a custom field that does not exist in the `HPIQuestionBank` model to serializers.py file and so far the code is as below but I am getting and error. I'm aware the `checkboxes` and `checkboxValues` are not attributes of the model but my goal is to make them `custom fields` where am I going wrong? `answer_type` is a custom field and it's ok and working correctly.

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `checkboxes` on serializer `TemplateQuestionBankSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `HPIQuestionBank` instance.
Original exception text was: 'HPIQuestionBank' object has no attribute 'checkboxes'.
```

**serializer**

```
class TemplateQuestionBankSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer_type = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    checkboxes = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(write_only=True))
    checkboxValues = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(write_only=True))

    class Meta:
        model = HPIQuestionBank
        fields = ['id','label','answer_type','checkboxes','checkboxValues']
```

**models**

```
class HPIQuestionBank(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        db_index=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    template = models.ForeignKey(
        HPIFilter, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    organization = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your serializer field definition, you have

```
checkboxes = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(write_only=True))
```

Here you have defined child fields as **write_only**, but haven't defined the ListField like that, so the serializer is trying to get its value while serilalizing. You need to define those fields like:

```
checkboxes = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(write_only=True), write_only=True)
checkboxValues = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(write_only=True), write_only=True)
```

You may not need to add **write_only** to child field definitions, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: it's weird @Ozgur Akcali If I try to nest the TemplateQuestionBankSerializer into another serializer I don't see the custom fields.

Comment: @pmutua that's probably because the field are defined as __write_only__ . When so, fields won't be present in the serialized object

Comment: I see, based on  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/  I think I have limited options. If I remove the write_only=True I will end up going back to the initial problem above. Still I want to see the fields when I do the nesting what is your take on this situation?

Comment: Where do you save these values? If they are saved in a model related to __HPIQuestionBank__, you can define their own serializers, and use those serializer as a nested serializer in __HPIQuestionBank__, this way you won't need to define them as write_only. If not, you can add __SerializerMethodField__ s for values of these fields with different names, in this scneario you will be using __checkboxes__ and __checkboxValues__ for writing, and newly added __SerializerMethodField__ s for reading their values for serializtion

Comment: The checkboxValues will be a list of  the `HPIAnswers.value ` and checkboxes are `HPIAnswers.answer_type`  as you can see in this gist: https://gist.github.com/pmutua/bec80480447f9201a02726f90bbdba18

Comment: I think the using serializer method field is a better option

Comment: @pmutua however sutils you better, but if you have a relation at the model level, it would be better to reflect this in your serializers as well